# How to save custom meta boxes in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been trying to get my custom meta box data to save in Wordpress, and I haven't had any luck. I've tried researching other posts, but since everyone does it a little bit differently, I haven't had any success at using the tutorials and other posts out there.

I created a metabox:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'ic_add_heading_box' );

function ic_add_heading_box( $post ) {

    add_meta_box(
            'Meta Box',
            'Heading Titles',
            'ic_heading_box_content', 
            'page', 
            'normal',
            'high'
        );

}

function ic_heading_box_content( $post ) {

    echo '<label>Main Heading (h1)</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="heading_box_h1" value="" />';
    echo '<label>Sub Heading (h3)</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="heading_box_h3" value="" />';

}
```

I just can't for the life of me get the data I insert in to the fields to save in Wordpress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look on the documentation, there is a nice example from start to end. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Answer (score 3):

The function you are using is only a display function.
You are not actually doing nothing with the data . it is only for creating the metabox. not handling it.

You need to add

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );
```

and then use [update_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) with a function like in the [codex example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Procedural) :

```
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

  // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return $post_id;

  // Check the user's permissions. If want
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

  } else {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
  }

  /* OK, its safe for us to save the data now. */

  // Sanitize user input. if you want
  $mydata = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] );

  // Update the meta field in the database.
  update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $mydata ); // choose field name
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I added that code to my file, and it obviously doesn't work because I need to edit some of those variables and values.  I still cannot seem to edit the right fields. Is there any way you could be a bit more specific based on my code above?